# Linux bash - how to run a list of binary files that is generated from another script?

Tags: linux, pipe

I have a script that generates list of binary files to be executed:

```
\home\joe\bin\script1
\home\joe\bin\script2
\home\joe\bin\script3
..
```

Question 1:
How can I run all of these files one by one from command line? One way of doing it is to cat the list of binary files to a temporary file `temp.sh` and run the `.sh` file. Is it possible to do it without creating a temporary `.sh` file?

Question 2: How can I run all of these file in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GNU Parallel:

Question 1:

```
list_generator_program | parallel -j1
```

Question 2:

```
list_generator_program | parallel
```

This will run one job per CPU core in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

antislashes in your example should be slashes, I guess

```
yarl@nb$ pwd
/tmp
yarl@nb$ cat list  
#!/bin/sh

echo /tmp/foo
echo /tmp/bar
yarl@nb$ cat foo
#!/bin/sh

echo I say foo
sleep 2
echo I say foo
yarl@nb$ cat bar
#!/bin/sh

echo And I say bar
sleep 2
echo And I say bar
yarl@nb$ cat parallel 
#!/bin/sh

./list | while read cmd; do
$cmd &
done
```

To run:

```
./list | sh
```

in parallel:

```
./parallel
```

Note that if 'list' lists n files, that's n jobs that runs in parallel. If you want to control that, use a counter or gnu parallel or something.
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547787/running-shell-script-in-parallel